# Formatar data ao realizar Update no registro - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou salvando no meu banco de dados a data em que determinado registro for alterado, porém o formato que o mesmo é salvo é **(YYYY-MM-DD)**, o comando SQL usado até então é o seguinte:

```
update public.transportadora set status = 'Ativo', user_update = 'Teste', data_alteracao = current_date where codigo = 3
```

e o registro fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha necessidade é que a data fique na sequencia **DD-MM-YYYY**, ou seja, **27/03/2017**

Comment: Você precisa se adaptar a reconhecer o banco como uma camada transparente feita para armazenar e manipular dados. Ele vai retornar um tipo de dados, a exibição desse tipo não é necessariamente obrigação dele. Você pode exibir como desejar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nível de banco de dados, se você selecionou esse campo como sendo um campo date ou timestamp você não formata a data, quem faz isso é o proprio banco, o que você pode fazer é pegar esse dado e formatar programaticamente, por exemplo em java pode usar o `SimpleDateFormat` em php se não me engano tem a função `date()`; Diz aí qual linguagem está usando que alguém dará uma resposta mais precisa.

Comment: Minha dúvida é se no próprio comando de Update eu poderia formatar o modo como a data é salva no banco não em si no `select` mas pelo que você já falou isso não é possível

Comment: No caso de BUSCAR os dados vc pode usar funções do SGBD para fazer isso por exemplo a date do MySQL, mas para salvar eh o SGBD que decide como salvar.

Comment: Sim, percebi pelo que você havia comentado

Answer (score 0):

Ao exibir utilize: `to_char(seu_campo_data, 'DD-MM-YYYY')`

Comment: Eu não tenho dificuldade para formatar para exibir, a resposta do @VictorHarturdeCarvalho mostrou isso

Comment: Você está confundindo formato de armazenamento com formato de exibição. Você não modifica o formato de armazenamento de um campo date no PostgreSQL, mas pode alterar o formato de exibição para a maneira que julgar conveniente.